# ¿Cómo pasar los valores de los input generados con jquery a la base de datos?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc-5

Estoy generando varios  en una tabla de forma que el usuario pueda personalizar las preguntas de una encuesta a realizar.

```
$(function () {
            var i = 1;
          $('#add').click(function () {
              //alert("hola");
              i++;
              $('#dinamic_field').append('<tr id="row"' + i + '""><td><input type="text"  name="name[]" id="name" placeholder="Pregunta personalizada..." class="form-control"/></td><td><button type="button" name="remove" id="' + i + '" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm btn_remove">X</button></td></tr>');
            });
          $(document).on('click', '.btn_remove', function () {
                //var btn_Id = $(this).attr("id");
              $('#row').remove();
          });

        });
```

[image: se generan de esta forma]

Necesito llevar todas las preguntas que se escriban en esas cajas de texto a un campo en una tabla llamada formularios el campo de llama preguntas. su ayuda por favor

Comment: pues solo recibes en el controlador string[] name

Comment: Estás en un entorno con ASP.NET MVC? Si es así, lo mejor sería detallar tu código del controller también, tanto para mostrar la pantalla como al momento de hacer le POST.

Answer (score 0):

para ello necesitas hacer estas dos funciones y una variable:

```
function send(a) {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: a,
        data: {json:JSON.stringify(data)  },
        success: success
    });
}

function eachInput(a,b) {
    var list = document.getElementsByTagName('input');
    for (var i in list) {
        if (list[i].className === a) {
            var x = list[i].value;
            send(b+x);
        }
    }
}

var url= 'http://www.somedatabase.com/?apikey=123456&values=';
```

Cómo usarlo?, mira:

```
eachInput('classname','values'); // values son los valores del URL.
```

Ejemplo:

eachInput('form-control','http://www.basededatos.com/?api=123&values=');

Lo que ah de hacer eachInput es, a todos los input con la clase form-control les extraera el value o valor luego lo enviara cada uno a la url que especifiques.